# Unexplainable lack of performance improvement using RxJava Observables in Web Applications

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java, netflix

I am performing some tests to evaluate if there is a real advantage in using reactive API's based on Observables, instead of the blocking traditional ones.

The whole example is [available on Githug](https://github.com/codependent/spring-nio-rest)

Surprisingly the results show that the thoughput results are:

- **The best**: REST Services that return a `Callable`/`DeferredResult` that wraps the blocking operations.
- **Not that bad**: Blocking REST Services.
- **The worst**: REST Services that return a DeferredResult whose result is set by a **RxJava Observable**.

This is my Spring WebApp:

**Application**:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringNioRestApplication {

   @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor(){
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(20);
        return executor;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringNioRestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**SyncController**:

```
@RestController("SyncRestController")
@Api(value="", description="Synchronous data controller")
public class SyncRestController {

    @Autowired
    private DataService dataService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/sync/data", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Gets data", notes="Gets data synchronously")
    @ApiResponses(value={@ApiResponse(code=200, message="OK")})
    public List<Data> getData(){
        return dataService.loadData();
    }
}
```

**AsyncController**: With both raw Callable and Observable endpoints

```
@RestController
@Api(value="", description="Synchronous data controller")
public class AsyncRestController {

    @Autowired
    private DataService dataService;

    private Scheduler scheduler;

    @Autowired
    private TaskExecutor executor;

     @PostConstruct
    protected void initializeScheduler(){
        scheduler = Schedulers.from(executor);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/async/data", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Gets data", notes="Gets data asynchronously")
    @ApiResponses(value={@ApiResponse(code=200, message="OK")})
    public Callable<List<Data>> getData(){
        return ( () -> {return dataService.loadData();} );
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/observable/data", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
     @ApiOperation(value = "Gets data through Observable", notes="Gets data asynchronously through Observable")
     @ApiResponses(value={@ApiResponse(code=200, message="OK")})
     public DeferredResult<List<Data>> getDataObservable(){
         DeferredResult<List<Data>> dr = new DeferredResult<List<Data>>();
         Observable<List<Data>> dataObservable = dataService.loadDataObservable();
         dataObservable.subscribeOn(scheduler).subscribe( dr::setResult, dr::setErrorResult);
         return dr;
     }
}
```

**DataServiceImpl**

```
@Service
public class DataServiceImpl implements DataService{

    @Override
    public List<Data> loadData() {
        return generateData();
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<List<Data>> loadDataObservable() {
        return Observable.create( s -> {
            List<Data> dataList = generateData();
            s.onNext(dataList);
            s.onCompleted();
        });
    }

    private List<Data> generateData(){
        List<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<Data>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            Data data = new Data("key"+i, "value"+i);
            dataList.add(data);
        }
        //Processing time simulation
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dataList;
    }
}
```

I have set a `Thread.sleep(500)` delay to increase the service response time.

There results from the load tests are:

**Async with Callable**: 700 rps, no errors

```
>>loadtest -c 15 -t 60 --rps 700 http://localhost:8080/async/data    
...
Requests: 0, requests per second: 0, mean latency: 0 ms
Requests: 2839, requests per second: 568, mean latency: 500 ms
Requests: 6337, requests per second: 700, mean latency: 500 ms
Requests: 9836, requests per second: 700, mean latency: 500 ms
...
Completed requests:  41337
Total errors:        0
Total time:          60.002348360999996 s
Requests per second: 689
Total time:          60.002348360999996 s
```

**Blocking**: around 404 rps but produces errors

```
>>loadtest -c 15 -t 60 --rps 700 http://localhost:8080/sync/data    
...
Requests: 7683, requests per second: 400, mean latency: 7420 ms
Requests: 9683, requests per second: 400, mean latency: 9570 ms
Requests: 11680, requests per second: 399, mean latency: 11720 ms
Requests: 13699, requests per second: 404, mean latency: 13760 ms
...
Percentage of the requests served within a certain time
  50%      8868 ms
  90%      22434 ms
  95%      24103 ms
  99%      25351 ms
 100%      26055 ms (longest request)

 100%      26055 ms (longest request)

   -1:   7559 errors
Requests: 31193, requests per second: 689, mean latency: 14350 ms
Errors: 1534, accumulated errors: 7559, 24.2% of total requests
```

**Async with Observable**: **not more than 20 rps, and gets errors sooner**

```
>>loadtest -c 15 -t 60 --rps 700 http://localhost:8080/observable/data
Requests: 0, requests per second: 0, mean latency: 0 ms
Requests: 90, requests per second: 18, mean latency: 2250 ms
Requests: 187, requests per second: 20, mean latency: 6770 ms
Requests: 265, requests per second: 16, mean latency: 11870 ms
Requests: 2872, requests per second: 521, mean latency: 1560 ms
Errors: 2518, accumulated errors: 2518, 87.7% of total requests
Requests: 6373, requests per second: 700, mean latency: 1590 ms
Errors: 3401, accumulated errors: 5919, 92.9% of total requests
```

The Observable executes with a corePoolSize of 10, but increasing it to 50 didn't improve anything either.

What could be the explanation?

**UPDATE**: As suggested by akarnokd I made the following changes. Moved from Object.create to Object.fromCallable in the service and reused the Scheduler in the controller, but still I get the same results.

Comment: Could you use `Observable.fromCallable` instead of `Observable.create`? Your use of `create` seems odd. In addition, Thread.sleep doesn't guarantee the sleep amount exaclty but depends on the OS. In the `getVideoInfoAsync` you are creating the Scheduler wrapper over and over unnecessarily.

Comment: Hi akarnokd, thanks for your comment. A couple of things, what's wrong with using Observable.create? Also I don't get what you mean by "creating the Scheduler wrapper over and over". To implement it I followed what I saw [here in dzone](https://dzone.com/articles/rx-java-subscribeon-and)

Comment: You don't call s.onCompleted() for a start, but the lack of handling unsubscription may be also problematic. In addition, you should see what the failure is which may also indicate the source of the performance loss. You have a TaskExecutor as a member field but then you wrap it with Scheduler.wrap for every invocation of `getVideoInfoAsync` which I'm guessing happens hundreds of times a second.

Comment: Mmm I also added `s.onCompleted()` in the original example but it didn't improve either. The only error I can see in the console is `o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed`

Comment: I'd change the observable to Observable.just and return some mocked object to rule out any deficiency with RxJava. Since RxJava doesn't do network, I presume you have a framework that does it instead. Based on the error message, it is possible this framework is misconfigured, outdated or simply buggy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was caused by a programming error at some point. Actually the example in the question works perfectly.

One warning to prevent others from having problems: beware of using `Observable.just(func)`, func is actually called on Observable creation. So any Thread.sleep placed there will block the calling thread

```
@Override
public Observable<List<Data>> loadDataObservable() {
    return Observable.just(generateData()).delay(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}

private List<Data> generateData(){
    List<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<Data>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        Data data = new Data("key"+i, "value"+i);
        dataList.add(data);
    }
    return dataList;
}
```

I started a discussion in [RxJava Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rxjava/B5s2Cm_Luko) where they helped me work it out.

Comment: So, what is the end result?

Comment: The result is that Observable's performance is slightly better than using just Callable.